# Kotlin binding any view model in the xml?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, viewmodel

I've implemented data binding and view model in my app, everything works great but I face a dumb issue which actually makes me wonder about re usability. 
I have a fragment which has a picture and a title from a database that I put in other fragments. It's all bind to the viewModel calling some getters.

My issue is I need it in another activity now which has a different viewmodel for clarity and also because I don't need all the livedata from before but I can't really give it the new viewmodel since when I define it the type is specific to the other one.

```
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.thegreenstring.view.ObjectiveViewModel" />
```

So what am I suppose to do? It kind of means that you can't reuse fragments unless you have the same view model right? Sucks a little. I thought the only workaround was to make a specific view model for this fragment but it feels a little weird no?

Thanks for your help in advance !

Comment: I don't know why I can't say hi in my post so hi everyone ! Lol

Comment: Just bind inside the fragment's XML ...

Comment: '''
 <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.thegreenstring.view.ObjectiveViewModel" />
'''
This is in the fragment XML